# Class: Object oriented paradigm had always confused me

Tags: c++, class

Can somebody please explain me clearly by using some nice examples how c++ class is useful and  why it is a good programming practice. I read a lot about class, did some programming in c++ using some classes but still I couldn't be clear why class are needed and how would they make the code more robust and readable.

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I'm afraid "everything about object-oriented programming" is going to be difficult to find in a single answer on Stack Overflow, or anywhere else.  There's... a lot to cover.

Comment: It's too broad as a question. An answer is a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type a script or 20 lines of code or 100 lines of code it's no big deal.

When you get to millions, you start to need a way to actually visualize your code.  You need to be able to talk of different sections and how they interact.

When you look at a long procedure, how is it organized?  When you have 20 functions, which ones correspond to what data?  Now document and remember it so the next time you look at the code you'll be able to get back to where you were right away.

Objects allow you to group functionality with the data it relates to.  It lets you find the functionality you need quickly.  Once you are used to it, it's hard to imagine why you would code without it.  I'm not sure how you'd diagram a design to show it to someone else without OO--Flow charts?  Really?

If you design your non-OO code Very Well with private variables (private to this file) and functions that relate to that data you can get some of this organizational effect, but it's messy and there is a lot of overhead.  Plus it's very easy for someone who doesn't quite "Get" OO to send the entire codebase spiraling to code-hell.

It's a very comfortable, logical sensible way to organize your code and data.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enroll in a CS program at a reputable school.
2. Take as many computer programming courses as possible.
3. Read a lot of books about Object Orientation (as well as old classics on procedural/modular programing.)
4. Rinse and repeat until you graduate.

By that time you should understand what a class is.

Comment: 5. Keep studying until you get somewhat productive at programming, not just writing exams. 6. Rinse and repeat until you retire!

Answer (score 1):

In a game, you have a class for a gun. It has a certain amount of ammo. You want to ensure that when firing the gun, one bullet is subtracted. When reloading, the clip size gets added back into the ammo.

Most importantly you want to maintain the "ammo" amount correctly. You **scope** it to an instance of a gun by **[encapsulating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_science%29)** all the variables that make up a gun. The users of the gun don't think about it much and don't have to worry about corrupting/screwing up the ammo (or other) values.

```
 class CGun
 {
 private:
    unsigned int ammo;
 public:
    CGun();
    void Reload() 
    { 
         if (ammo == 0)
         {
             ammo += 40/*40 bullets per clip*/
         }
    }

    void Fire() 
    {
        if (ammo > 0)
        {
            --ammo; 
        }
    }
 };
```

Now you can use this object very easily and safely without worrying about corrupting the underlying data.

```
 int main()
 {
     CGun aGun;
     aGun.Fire(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The oversimplified answer I'd give you is that when you notice that your programs tend to have 1) structures consisting of related data, and 2) a lot of functions that operate on those structures, then you have a class on your hands.

For example, in a real-time operating system, a task usually has a task control block structure, which contains a lot of information about the task such as its start pointer, its priority, the location of its stack, its status (ready to run, blocked on something, halted, not yet started, etc.), its name, and the location of any thread-specific globals. There are also a lot of functions that operate on the task which take a pointer to this task control block as a parameter. If this real-time operating system were written in C++, then you could create a Task class which contained the task control block's data, and the functions which operated on the task would be the class' methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely open-ended question, but in short classes provide a better representation between programming and real-world objects, concepts, and ideas that need to be considered. A class can be used to represent physical objects or concepts and the operations that you can perform on them. By linking the object and operations you can make the use and relationships more obvious, in short making the code easier to grasp (though in most cases still not trivial).